# change mouse event for product image magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to change the product double click event on the product image to single click to enlarge the Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

```
/js/varien/product.js
```

Change

```
Event.observe(this.imageEl, 'dblclick', this.toggleFull.bind(this));
```

to

```
Event.observe(this.imageEl, 'click', this.toggleFull.bind(this));
```

Comment: No way. Too easy for a Magento fix! (+1)